# Fifth last digit of a huge number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponentiation, congruences, power-towers

How can I find the fifth last digit of $5^{5^{5^{5^5}}}$? I tried to evaluate $5^{5^{5^{5^5}}}\pmod {100000}$. But the exponent is so huge that I'm unable to evaluate it. Also, $(5,100000)=5$ , so $5$ and $100000$ are not coprime, so Euler's totient theorem seems to be useless.

Comment: $100000 = 2^5\cdot 5^5$. the remainder of $5^{5^{5^{5^5}}}$ modulo both prime powers is easy to find. Then use the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: $10000=2^4\cdot 5^4$, and you might want to use Chinese reminder theorem. It's clear what your number is $\mod 5^4$, and you can use Euler's theorem for $\mod 2^4$.

Comment: The exponent is in fact too huge to directly calculate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your title asks one question ("fifth last digit") and the body of your question asks a different one ("number modulo 10,000"), which is a bit confusing. Fortunately the same answer applies to both.

The last five digits of the 5th, 6th, 7th,... 13th powers of 5 are 03125, 15625,78125, 90625, 53125, 65625, 28125, 40625, 03125, at which point the sequence obviously repeats. Thus the last 5 digits of $5^n$ (for $n\ge 5$) depend only on the value of $n\pmod 8$.

Your number, $5^{5^{5^{5^5}}}$, is $5^n$ where $n=5^{5^{5^5}}$. To know its last five digits, we need to work out the value of $n\pmod 8$. The remainders after dividing the 0th, 1st and 2nd powers of 5 by 8 are 1, 5, 1, after which the sequence obviously repeats. Thus odd powers of 5 equal 5 modulo 8 and even powers of 5 equal 1 modulo 8.

$n=5^{5^{5^5}}$ is an odd power of 5, so $n\pmod{8}=5$. Consequently the last 5 digits of $5^{5^{5^{5^5}}}=5^n$ are 03125. Therefore:

1. The answer to the question asked in your title is "0".
2. The answer to the question asked in the body is "3125".

Comment: With the help of $5^4=1$ modulo $16$, the answer can be derived a bit easier, but I nervertheless upvoted the very good answer.

Comment: But keep in mind, that you should first wait, whether the OP can solve the exercise with the given hints. The spirit of this forum is that the OP calculates as much as possible him/herself.

Comment: (+1) for this good solution.  I just have question why we choose $n\pmod 8$.
not any other number?

Comment: This is because the sequence 03125, 15625,78125, 90625, 53125, 65625, 28125, 40625, 03125,… has a period of 8 (the 9th number equals the 1st number, the 10th number equals the 2nd number, and so on). So when working out the value of the $n$th number of the sequence you can ignore all multiples of 8 – or, to put it another way, only the value of $n\pmod 8$ actually matter.

Comment: @MartinKochanski thanks I get it now